# How to change the Navigator.HardwareConcunrrency with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, navigator

## Problem:

I am making a bot, and updating it to let it be the more stealth as possible.

Here below is the full code :

```py
def print_hi(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print('Testing Selenium')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.
    print(selenium.__version__)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # Create ChromeOptions and set arguments
    options.add_argument("--user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'")

    # Initialize the ChromeDriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    # Define the initial JavaScript script
    initial_script = """
    Object.defineProperty(Notification, 'permission', {
        get: function () { return ''; }
    });
    window.chrome = true;
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
        get: () => false;
    });
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'chrome', {
        get: () => true;
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: 'works'
    });
    navigator.plugins.length = 1;
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'language', {
        get: () => 'el - GR'
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'deviceMemory', {
        get: () => 4
    });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'hardwareConcurrency', {
        get: () => 4
    });
    """

    # Execute the initial script using ExecuteCdpCommand
    cmd_params = {
        "source": initial_script
    }
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", cmd_params)

    #options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe'
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    # driver.execute_script('Object.defineProperty(navigator, "hardwareConcurrency", { get: function () { return 4; } })')
    driver.get('https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/')
    # driver.get('https://bot.sannysoft.com/')
    # driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("cnpj").value="35258556000167";')
    # cnpjInput = driver.find_elements(By.TAG)

    # Wait for a few seconds before quitting (you can perform actions here)
    time.sleep(500)  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed

    # Quit the browser
    driver.quit()
```

I need that the Navigator.HardwareConcurrency change to 4, but it is no occurring, wha am i missing ?

I tried diferents values and sintax of the function

I tried diferent values for 'get' function and diferents sintax.

Comment: I try somethings and get this solution :

    scriptNavigator = """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'hardwareConcurrency', { get: () => 4 });
    """

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {"source": scriptNavigator})